# Rails renders wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, render

I'm not really sure what is going on here. I am writing an blog and in this blog I have a tag_controller. In this tag_controller I have this action

```
3   def show
4     @blog_posts = BlogPost.published.tagged_with(params[:tag]).paginate(:page =>   params[:page], :per_page => 5)
5     render 'blog_posts/index'
6   end
```

But it fails with a template missing exception. In my logfiles I can see it's looking for a template file in tag/blog_posts/index (inside views of course). But why is it doing that. Shouldn't it go directly for app/views/blog_posts/index.html.erb ?

In any case, how do I make my app find the correct template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have missing the leading slash in the path, thus rails is trying to find the view in the current controllers view directory i.e tags

do

```
render '/blog_posts/index'
```